# What does というように mean?

Tags: grammar, nuances, particles

I've been seeing this structure a lot lately, and I feel like it takes on different meanings depending on how it's used.

Basically I understand it as:

```
Quotative と + いう(to say, define etc.) + ように (like)

AというようにB = "to do B like to say A" "to do B as if to say A"
```

Also, apparently it's synonymous with  と言わんばかりに

Not sure if I understand this correctly though.

Here are some sentences:

> 1. 分かった**というように**うなずき始める。 To start nodding as if to say he understood.

This sentence seems to fit in with my understanding above.

> 2. 夏には冷たい飲み物、冬には温かい飲み物**というように**、気温の変化に合わせて、飲み物を冷たくしたり、温かくしたりして出してくれる。（自動販売機）It serves drinks suited to the change in temperature by making it warm and cold, as if to say cold drinks in the summer, warm drinks in the winter (doesn't sound natural)

I can't seem to fit the translation with above, this というように appears to take on different meaning

> From one of the answers to a question on [hinative](https://hinative.com/ja/questions/12278013)
>
> 3. 「ソニーのような会社」の「ような」は、 ソニーと同じようにテレビを作っている会社、ソニーと同じように有名な会社、**というように**、(漠然とした)同じという意味。
>
> The "ような" in "ソニーのような会社" means a company that makes televisions like
>   Sony, a company famous like Sony, as if to say, same as (vague).

This というように seems disconnected, and I'm not sure how it works.

Can someone explain how というように is used in each of these sentences and how it works grammatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The「というように」in the second and third examples is hard to translate, but you could kind of imagine it as if it gave quotation marks to the previous statement, like「『夏には冷たい飲み物、冬には温かい飲み物』というように…」. In this sense, the literal meaning would still be akin to "As if to say, 'cold drinks in the summer, warm drinks in the winter', (...)". Still, it doesn't turn it into an actual quote; the「というように」simply denotes that what precedes it is an example that supports the following statement.

"And so on" as it is used in English is relatively similar (although I would hesitate to refer to it as an "exact equivalent"). As such, you could interpret the whole sentence in the second example to mean something to the effect of "It cools or warms the drinks before serving them in a way that matches changes in the outside temperature: hot drinks in the winter, cold drinks in the summer, and so on."

In the third example, its function is again to point out that whatever was said previously was an example and whatever follows is the main statement that these examples were given for. You could think of the whole sentence like "The ような in「ソニーのような会社」means 'similar to' in a vague sense; it could mean 'A company that manufactures TVs, like Sony', 'a famous company like Sony', and so on."

In other cases it can also denote that what precedes it is a set of examples (or sometimes a single example) for a statement that was made right before these examples were given. In this case it would be used like「気温の変化に合わせて、飲み物を冷たくしたり、温かくしたりして出してくれる。夏には冷たい飲み物、冬には温かい飲み物、というようにね。」

Answer (score 0):

Xというように would literally mean "in a way which says X". From which we can extrapolate:

分かったというように = in a way which says he understood = as if to say that he understood.

冬には温かい飲み物というように = in a way which says that it's warm drinks in winter = in a way which dictates it will be warm drinks in winter = in such a way that it will be warm drinks in winter.

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could interpret it as "the same as saying, as in". と言う say, ように same. ソニーのようなのような means "same" as in/the same as saying "a company famous like Sony."